# What's faster: Memcached or MySQL in memory table like HEAP?

Tags: mysql, memcached

If I have a pretty static set of data that I want to be able to access as quickly as possible. Should I cache the data into Memcached or should I store it in a HEAP table or something inside MySQL? Would one scale better than the other?

Is there some other option that's even faster?

Comment: Does this refer to a certain programming language?

Comment: Probably PHP, but I'm not beholden to it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

memcached will be faster for simple uses, hands down -- connection setup is so much cheaper on memcached, since there's no auth, buffer allocation, etc.  Also, memcached is designed to easily distribute keys between multiple servers.

However, memcached is only a simple key/value store.  If you need to do anything more complex to your data (even something like SELECT * WHERE x > 5), a HEAP table is much more powerful.

Robert Munteanu brings up a good point though.  Your cache hierarchy should be:

1. Globals (local to the request/process)
2. APC     (local to the server)
3. memcache (global)

If you don't need to propagate global changes to this data, then storing it in APC makes sense.  If you need to access it several times during script execution, you should also cache it in globals in your script.

Comment: So APC is faster than memcache? Even if php and memcache were on the same machine?

Comment: It should be -- it's basically just a shared memory segment, so any data access essentially only requires copying memory from one place to another.  Meanwhile, memcache requests happen through sockets, there's query parsing and deserialization overhead, etc.  Here's a benchmark supporting the globals -> APC -> memcached cache hierarchy: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/09/cache-performance-comparison/

Comment: fyi APC is found at http://pecl.php.net/package/APC and is dormant/dead according to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators#Alternative_PHP_Cache_.28APC.29  However APCu (user cache) had a release Jan 16 2017 http://pecl.php.net/package/APCu

Answer (score 3):

The fastest option would be in-memory caching on the local system. That won't scale well to many millions of relations, but will be *very* fast and work well for small data sets.

I haven't done performance testing between Memcached/MySQL HEAP, but I'd guess Memcached would be faster because it doesn't have the overhead of a full relational DB engine. Memcached would almost certainly scale better, because you could distribute it between servers and have a round-robin request dispatch between them.

If you need to perform any filtering on the data before retrieving it, you should use MySQL. The performance overhead of transmitting unwanted data will probably outweigh the benefits of faster lookups.

If I were you, I'd load the data set in question into MySQL *and* Memcached, then run performance tests to see which is better for your data set. If there's a core of data that's accessed particularly often, consider an additional machine-local cache.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a huge amount store it inside your own process. That's the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

I was using MYsql Memory based table,  Faster then memcached because of the queries. Memcached is key value store.

(even something like SELECT * WHERE x > 5),  Frank already wrote that.

I was doing very complex queires.  2 table.   If you have 1 GB data on Key value and if you want to filter. it takes time. Mysql faster in this case such as  "**where dt>123 and dt <321 and c=0**. "

Performance comparison Depends on usage.

" Concurrency for the MySQL MEMORY storage engine is not good for **inserts**. all concurrent threads doing **inserts** queue up against each other."